# Unable to insert data to database using PhP inside the modal

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

This modal once submitted will insert all the data to my database, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to work it out. As you can see once I clicked the button for "save changes" nothing works. I tried checking my database to see if something has been inserted but to no avail there's none. Can someone help me. Thanks.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog ">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" id="bg">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" >Sign Up</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="bg">

      <?php
      require('config/db_conn.php');
      if(isset($_POST['save']))
      {
         $fname=$_POST['firstName'];
         $lname=$_POST['lastName'];
         $add= $_POST['address'];
         $cont=$_POST['contact'];
         $user=$_POST['userName'];
         $pass=$_POST['paasWord'];
         $type=$_POST['selectType'];

         mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer (c_fname,c_lname,c_address,c_con,c_user,c_pass,c_type) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$add','$cont','$user','$pass','$type')") or die(mysql_error());

            header("location: login.php");

      }
      ?>

        <form method="post" action="">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputFirstName">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputFirstName" placeholder="Username" name="firstName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputLastName">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputLastName" placeholder="Username" name="lastName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputAddress">Address</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleInputAddress" placeholder="Address" name="address"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputContact">Contact</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputContact" placeholder="Contact" name="contact">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputUsername">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername" placeholder="Username" name="userName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password" name="passWord">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="examoleInputType">Type</label>
                    <select id="target" class="size form-control" name="selectType">
                        <option value="default" selected="selected">--SELECT--</option>
                        <option value="User">User</option>
                        <option value="Admin">Admin</option>    
                    </select>
            </div>

            <div class="well modal-footer" id="bg">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="save">Save changes</button>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

PS: I've put all the php code inside my modal along with the url of my database connection. The modal is place below the end tag html of this code. I'm using bootstrap from getbootstrap.com by the way.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])!="" ) {
    header("location: home.php");
} 

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Login</title>


<link rel = "stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<?php
require('config/db_conn.php');

?>

</head>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
background-color: #6BBEE4;

}

.createwrapper
{
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 118px;
}

a:hover
{
text-decoration: none
}

.size
{
width: 150px;
}

#bg
{
background-color: #6BBEE4;  

}

</style>
<body>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if($_POST['type'] == "User")
    {
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];


    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer where c_user = '$user' && c_pass = '$pass' && c_type = '$type'");

    $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    $_SESSION['username'] =  $data['c_user'];
    $_SESSION['password'] =  $data['c_pass'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $data['c_fname'];

    header("location: home.php");
    }

    elseif($_POST['type'] == "Admin")
    {
        echo "Were still working!!";
    }

    else
    {
    header("location: login.php");
    }
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#signup').click (function() {
        $('#myModal').modal(show);

    });


})


</script>

<div class = "well createwrapper">
<form method="post" action="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputUsername">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername" placeholder="Username" name="username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" name="password">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="examoleInputType">Type</label>

    <select id="target" class="size form-control" name="type">
    <option value="default" selected="selected">--SELECT--</option>
    <option value="User">User</option>
    <option value="Admin">Admin</option>    
    </select>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
  <div class="pull-right">
  <font color="428BCA"> Don't have an account? </font>
  <button class="btn btn-primary " name="signup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="signup">Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection...do not use this in a production environment. See: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: @tree don't worry I already know that. I'm still a student so it's just for educational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you never submit your form, it is only button. Change:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="save">Save changes</button>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="save" value="Save changes" />
```

Secondly, neither `header("location: login.php");` nor `header("location: home.php");` will not succeed, because you outputted html to the browser before calling those functions.

Comment: oh that, about the `header("location: login.php"); I just intentionally put that here for debugging purpose as for the `header("location: home.php"); it's fine it still works. Anyway I'll try your help to see if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A few things here that I think need clearing up in your mind.

First remember a model dialog is not a seperate page its just a div on the page that is cleverly positioned to look sexy.

Also I dont think the form in your model dialog will actually submit the form on the dialog i.e. the page as its a button and not an `<input type="submit"...>` unless you have written some javascript to notice the button click and submit the form from a javascript statement.

I would also suggest moving the PHP code from where you have it *in the model* as you call it, and move it to the top of the script controlling this page.

Remember that when you submit a form back to the server for processing, it starts the script from line one each time, so you should be processing any actions before rebuilding the page, so you know what page to throw back to the browser, or what contents to put on the page i.e. all it well OR woops there was an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is working and I'm using PDO for this.

EDIT: found a problem will update in a sec

Update: working now.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog ">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" id="bg">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" >Sign Up</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="bg">


<form method="post" action="insert.php"> // change to yours
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputFirstName">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputFirstName" placeholder="Username" name="firstName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputLastName">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputLastName" placeholder="Username" name="lastName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputAddress">Address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputContact" placeholder="address" name="address">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputContact">Contact</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputContact" placeholder="Contact" name="contact">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputUsername">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername" placeholder="Username" name="userName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password" name="passWord">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="examoleInputType">Type</label>
                    <select id="target" class="size form-control" name="selectType">
                        <option value="default" selected="selected">--SELECT--</option>
                        <option value="User">User</option>
                        <option value="Admin">Admin</option>    
                    </select>
            </div>

            <div class="well modal-footer" id="bg">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="save" value="Save changes" />
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

insert.php:

```
<?php
    require_once 'db_config.php'; 


    try {
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO test (c_fname, c_lname, c_address, c_con, c_user, c_pass, c_type)
            VALUES
            (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $sth->execute(array($_POST['firstName'],$_POST['lastName'],$_POST['address'],$_POST['contact'],$_POST['userName'],$_POST['passWord'],$_POST['selectType']));
        } catch (PDOException $pe) {
            die("Could not connect to the database $db_name :" . $pe->getMessage());
        }
?>
```

db_config.php:

```
<?php 
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_name = "db";
    $db_user = "root";
    $db_pass = "root";
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>
```